# Does the IEEE-754 standard mandate that exp2 is rounded correctly?

Tags: floating-point, libraries, accuracy

The [IEEE Standard for Floating-Point 
Arithmetic](https://www.csee.umbc.edu/%7Etsimo1/CMSC455/IEEE-754-2008.pdf) section *"9.2 Recommended correctly rounded functions"* lists functions that are recommended (but not required) by a language standard to provide, among them an `exp2` function as a particular example.

If a language provides `exp2`, does the standard *require* it to be correctly rounded?

As a particular example, I took the `exp2` function from the [openlibm](https://github.com/JuliaLang/openlibm) library, and found it to be correctly rounded in 99.96% of cases. However, in the rest of the cases (e.g., 37 cases from 100,000), it produced an answer that was off by 1 ulp. It's obviously very accurate, but it nevertheless was not correctly rounded in those 37 cases. Does this mean that the `exp2` function in `openlibm` is not IEEE-754 compliant?

Comment: So it's the difference between "(recommended correctly rounded) functions" and "recommended (correctly rounded functions)", right?

Comment: @Kirill yes, exactly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [1]: "However, the IEEE-754 standard specifies nothing for elementary functions" and "Indeed, the mathematical libraries (libm) provided by operating systems do not guarantee correct rounding.". As such, according to [1], the answer is that the IEEE-754 standard does *not* require the `exp2` function to be correctly rounded, it only recommends it.

[1] de Dinechin, F., Ershov, A. V., & Gast, N. (2005). Towards the Post-Ultimate libm. In 17th IEEE Symposium on Computer Arithmetic (ARITH’05) (pp. 288–295). IEEE. http://doi.org/10.1109/ARITH.2005.46